# Can I set an e-mail to send on a timer within Gmail?

Tags: gmail, scheduling

It's a business related e-mail, and I want it to get to the person before I wake up in the morning, but I don't want their first impression of me to be that I was awake at 3 a.m. sending e-mails.

Is there a way to set it to delay the sending of an e-mail I already typed by a few hours?

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this natively with GMail but you can do it with browser extensions:

- [Streak](http://streak.com) is free and has a "Send later" feature.
- [RightInbox](http://www.rightinbox.com/) is free for up to 10 emails per month
- [Boomergang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/) is free for up to 10 emails per month

Comment: how reputable is Streak?

Comment: @BeauBouchard As of April 10, 2019, Streak has 793,573 users, and they must do a pretty good job because a friend of mine recommended them to me.  They're probably a startup, so I doubt the data is the most secure, but also Streak's probably not the biggest target either (I'd imagine the biggest target is one of the older brick-and-mortar retailers who have bad password security).  So in summary, I doubt you have to worry about someone getting at your private e-mails unless a nosy Streak employee goes rogue

Comment: Thank you, I was asking this question in April 14, of 2014 I guess Streak almost got a million users in 5 years.

Answer (score 6):

Despite requests for this feature since 2009, the Gmail team [refused](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/JovisjFkzY8) to implement it.

There are however browser extensions and apps that let you schedule new emails or replies:

- **[Streak](http://streak.com)** is a free browser extension CRM for Gmail and has a "Send later" feature (you don't need to bother with the CRM at all). You can conveniently schedule a reply right from the Compose box. I've been using it for about a year and it works very well, except that if I change the Subject line, the message won't go through. You need to go in Drafts and Send it Later from there again, under the new Subject line. Works for Google Apps accounts, as well as Gmail. **Best choice.**
- [RightInbox](http://www.rightinbox.com/) is free for up to 10 emails per month, and supports email tracking via an embedded image (web bug). I've used it in its early stage while it was very buggy and corresponded with its author. You can schedule replies right from the Compose window.
- [Boomergang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/) is free for up to 10 emails per month. After that, it's $5/mo for Gmail accounts and $15 for Google Apps accounts.
- [Gmail Delay Send](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/) is a script you have to install via Google Docs. I tried it; the process was somewhat convoluted and the tool is rough and immature. It is however fully free and open source, and won't add any additional load to your browser (unlike extensions). **This is the most promising and most lightweight solution**. Unfortunately, it has seen [no development since May 2012](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/source/list).
- [Momento Mail](http://www.kymalabs.com/mmail) is a Google App (not a browser extension), and you have to use their own website. As of November 2013, it no longer works (directs to a blank page after typing in the scheduling and recipient info). To schedule a reply, you'd have to copy/paste the To, CC and email body from Gmail. Quite cumbersome. Their "To" field doesn't support the standard address format
  `Name <address@company.com>`. The message won't end up in your Gmail Sent folder, but you have an option to BCC yourself. Least recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Not via the web UI, no. You would need to use POP or IMAP and send the email from a client (such as Outlook, Thunderbird, and others) that supports delayed sending.

Comment: There are easier ways than having to use a POP/IMAP client and making sure that does support scheduled sending, and making sure your machine is on at the intended time. See [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42223/17089) that compares current solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Boomerang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/).

- Free
- Works with Gmail
- Easy to use
- Mentioned in lots of reputable sources like Inc magazine
  But
- It asks for information on your gmail account. I'm [not sure how safe that is.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22617/is-it-safe-to-allow-gmail-boomerang-pluggin-to-access-google-account)

Comment: I am using Boomerang on a regular basis. Worked every time so far. You need to install a Browser plugin, though.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=112802 This page explains what information Google shares with websites like Boomerang. Does not seem to be anything to worry about, as long as you trust the website, because the code that Google sends does not reveal any personal information and when you try to use Boomerang, it will ask for the email address associated with your account, so that it can contact you. At least this is my understanding of it.

Comment: But wouldn't Boomerang need to have access to my email account to be able to send email on my behalf (delayed), etc.? That seems like more than just 3rd party verification/signin.

Comment: I recently started using Boomerang too.  Yes, it sends e-mail later on my behalf.  I have to set when the e-mail gets sent.

Comment: Boomerang is only free for under 10 emails per month. See [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42223/17089) for a much better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a bit of script that you can install through Google docs that will let you save a draft with the delivery time and apply a label to have the email automatically sent.  I have not tried this myself, but it came up while I was looking for a solution to this problem.

http://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/

Comment: Google Code is gone. Do you have a better location?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a third-party app for that.

[TimeCave](http://www.timecave.com/) looks like it might do that for you. From their "about" page:

> The idea is simple: drop an email
>   message into Time Cave and tell it
>   when to come out. It'll stay there for
>   as long as you'd like, within reason.
>   (We wouldn't want stalactites to
>   dissolve it.) So for days, weeks,
>   months, or even years, Time Cave will
>   hold onto your message. Once the
>   message's time comes, it's speedily
>   sent on its way back toward you (**or
>   whomever you addressed it to**).

(emphasis mine)

Comment: timeCave requires their own email account. Can I use my own gmail/hotmail/yahoo/pop account to do that ?

Comment: The OP is looking for a Gmail-specific solution (probalby to easily schedule replies, and to keep the correct email trail in the Sent folder). TimeCave requires you to use their own website, and DeferredSender is dead. Please consider deleting this answer?

Comment: There is no solution in Gmail. A third party solution is the only option.

Comment: While there is no solution *in* Gmail itself (as in, provided by Google), there are solutions that worth *with* Gmail, such as the ones I pointed out in [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42223/17089).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it completely inside Google - without any third-party applications.

Digital Inspiration provides a script that you can run in a Google Spreadsheet. It draws the message IDs from your drafts and let's you select a date for the message to be sent. Another column tells you the status of each message (Not Scheduled, Scheduled, Delivered, etc).

You can make a copy of the original spreadsheet into your own Google Drive by finding the link on the blog - http://www.labnol.org/internet/schedule-gmail-send-later/24867/.

For a detailed 3 minute demo, check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhU5y7huAY8

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's a very easy way to do that. You can read more about it [here](https://www.theverge.com/2019/5/6/18530967/how-to-schedule-email-gmail-natively-desktop-mobile-app).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ## 2019 update

#### It can now easily be done from within Gmail.

Apr 1, 2019 [Official Google announcement](https://www.blog.google/products/gmail/hitting-send-on-the-next-15-years-of-gmail/)

> *... you can decide when your email gets delivered to someone else’s inbox. Today, we added a **new feature that lets you schedule email to be sent at a more appropriate date or time**, which is helpful if you’re working across time zones, or want to avoid interrupting someone’s vacation.*

You can **find info** on how to use the new feature in the official [Google help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9214606)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I stumbled on this thread while trying to answer this question my self.  I've just installed Send Later and it seems to work well.

1. Go to tools - Addons
2. Type "send later" in the search bar.
3. Install and restart Thunderbird.

To add a timer to a message hit control-shift-enter. Set your time for sending and press the "send later at time(s) specified above".  Relax in the knowledge that no one knows you write your work emails at 3 in the morning. :)

Comment: So this is a Thunderbird tool? That's great, except that this is Web Apps, so the assumption is that there is a web-based solution for this. The OP did not mention anything about using a desktop client.

Answer (score -4):

Microsoft outlook works well and will do it through any email you choose

Comment: This doesn't add anything that [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/2937/) doesn't already cover.