# Can I schedule to send mail later on with duration on Gmail?

Tags: gmail, scheduling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I set an e-mail to send on a timer within gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/can-i-set-an-e-mail-to-send-on-a-timer-within-gmail)

I'd like to schedule an email at a later time and date with Gmail.

Is this possible?

They have many goodies in their labs section of Gmail preferences, but I do not recall seeing this labs add-on.

Comment: The [best answer is here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42223/17089).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Boomerang](http://www.baydin.com/boomerang4gmail/) extension

Comment: Boomerang for Gmail is in closed Beta.
Register for an invitation.

Awaiting for registration code :) Thanks

Comment: A much more comprehensive answer is on the [original](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/can-i-set-an-e-mail-to-send-on-a-timer-within-gmail/42223#42223) (non-duplicate) question. Care to self-delete this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set up your Gmail account using an IMAP compatible client, you can use this client to delay send emails from your Gmail account.

Here are step-by-step instructions for doing this using Outlook 2007:
[Schedule Email in Gmail – Delay Send](http://pleasantonwebdesignblog.com/2010/07/schedule-email-in-gmail-delay-send.html)