# How do I send a scheduled email within Gmail?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Schedule an email to send at a specific date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12137/schedule-an-email-to-send-at-a-specific-date)

I heard you can send pre-scheduled emails within Gmail; where is this feature located?  Can I choose a specific time etcetera?  How many pre-scheduled emails can be set for a single email address?

Comment: @AlEverett: not a duplicate, I saw that.  I read somewhere recently that Gmail had implemented this feature so I wanted to know where it is.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Can I set an e-mail to send on a timer within Gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/can-i-set-an-e-mail-to-send-on-a-timer-within-gmail/42223#42223)